# Using SonarQube to distribute checkstyle for multiple projects including Suppressions for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, checkstyle

We want to use Sonar as distributor for our checkstyle configuration. This is easy with Sonar's permalinks. 
The problem are the suppressions. If we add the suppressions global at GeneralSettings → Java → Checkstyle like:

```xml
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="someFolder/suppressed_checks.xml"/>
</module>
```

there will be the same suppressions configuration for every checkstyle configuration via the permalink. 
If we add the SuppressionFilter module only for the checkstyle for one Project then it won't be included in the file from the permalink.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My question would be: why do you want to keep using Checkstyle if you're using SonarQube?

Comment: We want to use checkstyle in Eclipse too. This way every developer can instantly see checkstyle problems.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to use SonarQube in Eclipse?