# Including Checkstyle suppressions in SonarQube Checkstyle Permalink to use in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, sonarqube, permalinks, checkstyle

I want to use Sonar's Checkstyle configuration in our Eclipse environment for on-compile-time analysis of our rules.
Therefore I've already included the permalink of Sonar's quality profile in Eclipse Checkstyle plug-in. However the generated Checkstyle configuration XML file only contains an empty SuppressionCommentsFilter tag.

I want to include our project specific suppressions XML file in the configuration as well. I've set the link to the suppressions.xml in the project settings for the Checkstyle plug-in.

Is there a way to include the suppressions configuration in the permalink generated from sonar? Or is there a different approach that I should try to accomplish this?

Using SonarQube Eclipse plug-in on full maven builds only isn't an option as mentioned in this similar question ([Using SonarQube to distribute checkstyle for multiple projects including Suppressions for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889430/using-sonarqube-to-distribute-checkstyle-for-multiple-projects-including-suppres)) as I want fast feedback about most violations and errors when saving code changes the same way it is offered by Eclipse Checkstyle plug-in (and others like PMD and FindBugs).

My current impression is that there is a discrepancy between project configuration and reusable quality profiles. I should be able to reuse profiles for new projects in Sonar - which I can - but import project settings in other applications - which i can't right now.